# How to fix. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'. VERSION@value value=(26.1.0)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-support-library

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.1.0) from [com.android.support:design:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.0.1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

## build.gradle : Project

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

### build.gradle : Module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jystinz.roomdatabase"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // reactive Network
    compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:0.11.0'

    // room persistence
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.0.0-alpha9'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9'

    // images
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    // barcode
    compile 'com.github.KingsMentor:MobileVisionBarcodeScanner:2.0.0'

    // retrofit2
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

    // gps
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'

    // dialog
    compile 'com.avast:android-styled-dialogs:2.3.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.7'
}
```

->>> [Images](http://postto.me/1m/o4u.png).

Thank you.

Comment: Did you figure out a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add in your `dependencies`

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 41):

Library `com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.1` has a meta tag inside its manifest

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.0.1" />
```

Your another library `com.android.support:design:26.1.0` has this meta tag

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />
```

When we build the app library manifests will merge so multiple libraries have the same meta tag with the different value. it will cause conflict.

If you want to get rid of this add this meta tag in your app manifest

```
<meta-data
        tools:replace="android:value"
        android:name="android.support.VERSION"
        android:value="26.1.0" />
```

Comment: This is a great answer. In addition to solving the problem, it also explains why it occurs in the first place. Thank you very much

Comment: awesome, you are great!

Comment: Great!, this works, do not forget to add xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" to manifest tag

Answer (score 2):

**

```
<**application
....
..... <meta-data
            tools:replace="android:value"
            android:name="android.support.VERSION"
            android:value="26.1.0" />
</application**
```

**
just add this to get rid of the conflict